# How to do Russian text validation in java using GNU's Regex..?

Tags: rfc1123

I did internationalization for my website.So my website also available in Russian language.But while gathering user information of Russian user from my web page i am not able to validate entered text.Please give me solution to validate Russian text in java.Thanks in advance......!